# Redoing the align environment with a specific formatting

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, tikz-styles

I want to remake the \begin{align} environment  \end{align} with some stylization and I have no idea how I can do this. Well, to be precise, I want two specific things to happen in this environment:

1. I want each line break to add a vertical line where the command breaks, i.e.:
   [image]
2. When it is an operation other than equality, I want it to look like this when there is a line break:
   [image]

I have no idea how to start developing code that does this... Maybe using tikz should be a simpler alternative, but I don't know how to implement this.

> Both images that I posted I made the lines by hand drawing.

Comment: you could use tikzmark to record the position of the `=` then draw in the rules at the end

Comment: Can you give as the math equation setup so that we don't have to type up or own `align` environment. And indeed, @DavidCarlisle's approach comes to mind immediately, though you will need to use a macro for the `=` or an active `=` to make it automated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want these lines?

Comment: During my undergraduate studies I had a class with a professor who used these lines to line up the equations on the blackboard and with that I acquired the habit of using them too, so I wanted to pass this on to LaTeX too, because I think it looks very nice and organized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick `tikzmark` version (though without the library because we don't need any advances techniques it has to offer).

Change the `outer ysep` to adjust the white space between the `=` and the actual line. (The `inner ysep` will contribute to the bounder box and might change the vertical placement of lines if it is too big.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\newcommand*\eqlineset{\pgfqkeys{/eqlines}}
\eqlineset{
  picture/.style={baseline, remember picture},
  line/.style={thick, draw=orange, line cap=round},
  node/.style={
    minimum size=+0pt, inner sep=+0pt, outer ysep=+.3333em, anchor=base,
    name=tma\thetikzmarkalign},
}
\newcounter{tikzmarkalign}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{%
  \setcounter{tikzmarkalign}{0}%
  \newcommand*\noeq{\hphantom{{}={}}}%
  \newcommand*\eq{
    \ifnum\value{tikzmarkalign}=0
      \mathrel{\tikz[/eqlines/picture]\node[/eqlines/node]{$=$};}
    \else
      \mathrel{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[/eqlines/picture]
          \node[/eqlines/node] (tma\thetikzmarkalign) {$=$};
          \unless\ifmeasuring@
            \path[/eqlines/line, overlay] (tma\thetikzmarkalign)
                        -- (tma\pgfinteval{\thetikzmarkalign-1});
          \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    \fi
    \stepcounter{tikzmarkalign}
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 Lorem & \eq Ipsum \\
       & \eq dolor sit amet,\\
       & \noeq + \frac{consetetur sadipscing elitr}{sed diam nonumy} \\
       & \eq eirmod tempor invidunt.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If it's just a plain line I'd be inclined to implement this in PGF to not carry around the overhead of TikZ (and tikzmark). — I wonder if it is possible to get the spacing between the current and the last line from `amsmath` (it does measure a lot on its own already after all) and to just `\overset` the `=` with a vertical rule.

Comment: This warning mensage appears with this code:
"Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. Did you specify a point identical to the center of node ``tma1''? on input line 25."
How can I solve this??

Comment: @Jimeens I've edited my answer to remove that warning my using `\ifmeasuring@` that `amsmath` provides for when it only measures its environment's content, we can't draw anything then because those measurements aren't on the page which confuses PGF/TikZ.

Comment: @Jimeens It should be noted that this only works when the whole `align` is on the same page. If it spread out over multiple pages this needs to be adjusted (the `tikzmark` library also saves the page number so we could check where the other `=` is) and you will need to specify how the connection should look then.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, you can place the equals signs in `\tikzmarknodes` (add `{}` for proper spacing) and then use `tikz` to draw lines between these nodes (which can span over several lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    x & \tikzmarknode{eq1}{{}={}} a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \\
      & \tikzmarknode{eq2}{{}={}} (a + b)^2
\end{align}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[very thick, orange, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt] (eq1) -- (eq2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]